# how can i find all column with full text index in mysql 4.1.22

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, information-schema

I'm trying to find all column of a mysql database (4.1.22) whith a Full Text index.

With Mysql > 5.0 i can run this query

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.STATISTICS
WHERE index_type LIKE 'FULLTEXT%'
```

but information_schema is not supported in mysql 4.1.22, so i don't know anything else

Suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As documented under [`SHOW INDEX` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/show-index.html):

> [`SHOW INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/show-index.html) returns the following fields:
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> - `Index_type`
>
>   The index method used (`BTREE`, `FULLTEXT`, `HASH`, `RTREE`).
> - `Comment`
>
>   Various remarks. Before MySQL 4.0.2 when the `Index_type` column was added, `Comment` indicates whether an index is `FULLTEXT`.

You can then parse the results to determine over which columns `FULLTEXT` indexes have been defined.

Comment: so, do i have to run `show index from information_schema.xxxx` ?

Comment: @alesdario: No. You will need to obtain a list of all tables (perhaps by parsing the output from a [`SHOW TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/show-tables.html) command), then issue `SHOW INDEX` for each of them.

Comment: Your output is different from the query posted above. Information_schema return me all tables in all databases. In your way i have to query all over databases in my server.

Comment: @alesdario: Yes, you do.  But that is your only option from within MySQL v4.1.